# Maximal non-reducible vertex cover of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, time-complexity

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph (i.e. an undirected simple finite graph). 
We say that a [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) $V'$ of $G$ is *non-reducible* if any $V''$ with $V''\subsetneq V'$ is not a vertex cover of $G$. We say that a non-reducible vertex cover $V'$ of $G$ is *maximal* if for all non-reducible vertex cover $V''$ of $G$ we have $|V''|\le |V'|$. Note that the minimum vertex cover is non-reducible, but of course not necessarily maximal.

What is know about the (time)-complexity of finding a maximal non-reducible vertex cover?

Is there anything known for hypergraphs with multiple edges?

Answer (score 3):

What you call a non-reducible vertex cover is commonly known as a *minimal* vertex cover. So, what you are looking for is a minimal vertex cover of maximum cardinality, i.e a maximum minimal vertex cover.

I'm not aware of any literature on this problem per se, however the equivalent *Independent Dominating Set* problem is quite well studied. An *independent dominating set* in a graph $G$ is an independent set $I$ such that every vertex not in $I$ has a neighbor in $I$. In the *Independent Dominating Set* problem input is a graph $G$ and the task is to find a smallest possible independent dominating set. This problem is known to be NP-complete.

The two problems are equivalent because a set $S$ is a minimal vertex cover if and only if $V(G) \setminus S$ is an independent dominating set.

Answer (score 3):

Since the complement of a vertex cover is an independent set, 
the problem of finding a minimal vertex cover of maximum cardinality 
is equivalent to 
the problem of finding a maximal indpendent set of minimum cardinality.

- The problem of finding a maximal indpendent set of minimum cardinality has been studied extensively. The right search term is "well-covered graphs".
- In particular, the underlying decision problem is NP-complete. This follows (for instance) from the reduction in V. Chvátal and P.J. Slater, 
  "A note on well-covered graphs" in Annals of Discrete Math 55 (1993), 179–181.